# Error: Mat is ambiguous when using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am pretty new in c++ and i am trying to use some of the libraries OpenCV is offering. The problem is that when i put the code below it says:

> `Error: Mat is ambiguous`

, which i have read in other posts that means that the compiler cannot pick which function to choose, but this is exactly how it was called in the OpenCV tutorial too. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

```
Mat A;
```

EDIT: The code i have written till now is in the `.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#include <E:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <E:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace cv;
class Face_Detection
{
public:
    Face_Detection();

    ~Face_Detection();

};
int main(){

    cv::Mat image;
    //A = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You wrote `main()` in your header file?

Comment: I thought that it might not be the best idea but i come from java where the file was one at least how i used to work it so i try to make it as simple as possible. But is that why i have that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may include other lib/file that also defines a `Mat` type. Try to use, i.e. by explicitly add its namespace `cv`,

```
cv::Mat A;
```

instead to avoid ambiguity.

---

**Edit:**

The way you included OpenCV header files make me feel you didn't use OpenCV properly. Try to first follow the following post to setup OpenCV correctly, including `include/library/...`.

- http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work. Just 2 questions. Why does it need the cv in front even though i have included the files that the tutorial had too? And second it says that expects a ";" even though i have put it. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @user2466854 For Q1: just as said in the answer, you need this to avoid ambiguity. For Q2: have you install OpenCV already?

Comment: I have downloaded the .exe and it extracted the files if that is what you mean. And through the files i have included the two that are said. My code to be exact is the same as in the site of the tutorial till the line of the mat image.

Comment: @user2466854 Can you share the whole error message, I mean, all error messages if have others?

Comment: @user2466854 Follow the link I gave above to setup OpenCV correctly first and see how it goes.