# opencv: call to "Mat" is ambiguous

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I try to use opencv to calculate the HoG descriptor, but an error `call to "Mat" is ambiguous` was raised.

I saw the answer under [Error: Mat is ambiguous when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170934/error-mat-is-ambiguous-when-using-opencv)

and I don't know whether my includes are right.

and my includes for opencv are:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
```

here's the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < original[i]; j++) {
        cv::Mat train_original;
        train_original = cv::imread(original_path + std::to_string(j) + ".jpg", 1);

        cv::resize(train_original, train_resize_image, cv::Size(128, 128), 0, 0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        // 计算HOG descriptor
        cv::HOGDescriptor hog(cv::Size(128, 128), cv::Size(64, 64), cv::Size(16, 16), cv::Size(8, 8), 9);
        hog.compute(train_resize_image,train_descriptor);
        cv::Mat descriptor_mat(cv::Mat(train_descriptor).t());
        train_descriptors.push_back(descriptor_mat);
    }
```

where `train_descriptor` is in type of `std::vector<float>`

The error was raised in line

```
cv::Mat descriptor_mat(cv::Mat(train_descriptor).t());
```

Any help will be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: cv::Mat(train_descriptor).t() returns variable of type cv::MatExpr which cv::Mat has no constructor for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the following line:

`cv::Mat descriptor_mat(cv::Mat(train_descriptor).t());`

with

`cv::Mat descriptor_mat = cv::Mat(train_descriptor).t();`

since Mat `operator =` can handle `MatExpr` object, while `Mat` constructor can not(check [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a039eb3c6740a850696a12519a4b8bfc6)). But be careful with this method since it does not copy the data and shares it(like a pointer). Basically, if you want to copy the data you can do the following:

```
 cv::Mat descriptor_mat;
 cv::transpose(cv::Mat(train_descriptor),descriptor_mat);
```